# Is there another method for connecting a pc to a local lan printer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, printer

I'm trying to connect my pc to a printer connected on the LAN. But for some reason, it always fail when connecting and showing the error 0x000000011b.

Screenshot of error showing when trying to connect:

[image: Screenshot of Error Showing when trying to connect]

I've tried Everything including turning off the firewalls, Editing the Registry Editor, connecting on a TCP/IP connection, Uninstalling the problematic windows security update. But nothing seems to be working. Is there anyway to solve this issue for both Windows 7 and Windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried this [How to Fix Printer Error 0x0000011b ](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/error-0x0000011b.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to install the printer while connected via a
USB cable. This installs the necessary driver, so that wireless
printing may then be easier to do.

If Windows doesn't manage to install the printer, an alternative
method (which is possibly even better) is to download the offline
installation from HP and do the installation manually. For that, see
[Software and drivers for HP Smart Tank 510 Wireless All-in-One series](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-smart-tank-510-wireless-all-in-one-series/16449872).

If still encountering problems, one more advice I have seen
(which might not pertain to Windows 7) is:

- Run `regedit` and navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print`
- Create a DWORD (32-bit) value named `RpcAuthnLevelPrivacyEnabled`
- Set its value to `0` and reboot.